# Create windows console application that mirrors a valid application (Malware Class)

Tags: c#, process, console

I am teaching a class and am trying to show how you shouldn't trust applications on your system blindly.

The first demo is to run netstat and output the list of sockets connected.
I have created another application with the same name, but it omits the IP passed into arg[0] from the display.  The console output is the same.  The goal being that you can have a file named the correct name, but not necessarily legitimate. (Obviously hashes won't match)

The next demo is something like tasklist, though I have having trouble getting the "Session Name" from processes.GetProcesses.  If I run tasklist on the demo machine (XP) I can't find the value associated with it.  Also, is there a easy way to sort the list, as tasklist sorts on PID.  I am new to C# so bear with me.

Thanks!

```
Process[] procs = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process proc in procs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(image.PadRight(17) + pid.PadLeft(5) + sname.PadRight(16) + mem.PadLeft(12));
}
```

So the goal is to replicate tasklist (basic functionality) or another windows command line app to show that a real malware author could replicate all of it.

Update:
All the students will be running in on their own XP VM so I can't really have them connect somewhere else.  Being on XP also eliminates the UAC issue.

Comment: Maybe instead of going through all of this just to get a fake display for a demo, who not run real commands against a fake computer?  A laptop you've got stashed away somewhere.  Some of the sysinternals tools will do that.  The display will show a live, running system... just not the one you're controlling. If you've got Windows 7, then clever use of XP mode windows or a VM could get you the same thing on a single box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to just use any command-line app and inspect the text (and modify it if you wish):

```
    var exeName = @"tasklist.exe";
    var arguments = "";

    var process = new Process
    {
        EnableRaisingEvents = true,
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(exeName)
        {
            Arguments = arguments,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        },
    };

    process.OutputDataReceived += 
       (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("received output: {0}", e.Data);

    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();

    process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: That fits the bill exactly, and works for the most part.  I am doing a string.replace("csrss.exe","good1.exe").  I am getting a null reference exception, but I can just trap it and still show the output.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image name from the Process.Modules list (first element), the pid from the Process.Id property, and the memory from Process.Working set; but, you'll have to pinvoke WTSQuerySessionInformation to get the session name.  For example:

```
foreach(Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    IntPtr buffer;
    uint bytesReturned;
    WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, (uint) p.SessionId, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSWinStationName, out buffer, out bytesReturned);
    var sessionName = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buffer);
    WTSFreeMemory(buffer);
    string moduleName = p.ProcessName;
    try
    {
        moduleName = p.Modules[0].ModuleName;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex = ex;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-17} {1,5} {2,-16} {3,12} {4,12} K", moduleName, p.Id, sessionName, p.SessionId, (p.WorkingSet64 / 1024).ToString("n0")));
}
```

Which assumes the following is declared in the class:

```
enum WTS_INFO_CLASS
{
    WTSInitialProgram,
    WTSApplicationName,
    WTSWorkingDirectory,
    WTSOEMId,
    WTSSessionId,
    WTSUserName,
    WTSWinStationName,
    WTSDomainName,
    WTSConnectState,
    WTSClientBuildNumber,
    WTSClientName,
    WTSClientDirectory,
    WTSClientProductId,
    WTSClientHardwareId,
    WTSClientAddress,
    WTSClientDisplay,
    WTSClientProtocolType,
    WTSIdleTime,
    WTSLogonTime,
    WTSIncomingBytes,
    WTSOutgoingBytes,
    WTSIncomingFrames,
    WTSOutgoingFrames,
    WTSClientInfo,
    WTSSessionInfo
};

[DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = false)]
public static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr memory);
[DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool WTSQuerySessionInformation(
    IntPtr hServer,
    uint sessionId,
    WTS_INFO_CLASS wtsInfoClass,
    out IntPtr ppBuffer,
    out uint pBytesReturned
);
```